# creating a form to route a method inside controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a form that redirects to a method called accept_item on the form controller. My issue is that it's not going through the accept_item method when I submit the form.

**form_controller.rb**

```
def accept
    @form = Form.find(params['id'])
end
def accept_item
    redirect_to inventories_path
end
```

**accept.html.erb**

```
  <%= form_tag accept_item_forms_url do %>
      <% @form.items.each do |i| %>
          <%= label_tag 'Item Name' %>
          <p><%= i.name %></p>
          <%= label_tag 'Quantity' %>
          <p><%= text_field_tag 'quantity', i.quantity %></p>

      <% end %>
      <%= submit_tag 'Accept', class: 'btn btn-default btn-about pull-left', data: {confirm: 'Are you sure you want to accept?'} %>
  <% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
  resources :forms do
    collection do
      get :accept_item, :as => :accept_item
    end
  end
```

**Error Message**

```
No route matches [POST] "/forms/accept_item"
```

Comment: Forms use the `POST` method, you define your collection route as `get :accept_item`, you should `post :accept_item` instead.

Comment: That worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `form_tag` helper uses the HTTP `POST` method by default. You defined your routes with `get`:

```
get :accept_item, :as => :accept_item
```

You should use `post` instead:

```
post :accept_item, :as => :accept_item
```

Also I don't think you need the `as: :accept_item` part, unless you're going to use `accept_item_url` instead of `accept_item_forms_url`.

Comment: I have multiple items in my input field. How can I send it to my controller as an array?

Comment: @MarcosIcaza checkout [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992112/text-fields-from-array-in-rails) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089849/ruby-on-rails-submitting-an-array-in-a-form)

Answer (score 0):

just remove `:as => :accept_item`, and change method to `post`

```
post :accept_item
```

You will get `/foo` when using `:as => 'foo'`.